# How to use common service between modules?

Tags: nestjs

How to use a common service for multiple modules?

I have service

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  test(): number {
    return 123;
  }
}
```

I registered it in App module.

```
  providers: [TestService],
  exports: [TestService]
```

I want to use it in Products module and others.

```
@Module({
  imports: [TestService],
  controllers: [ProductsController],
  providers: [ProductsService]
})
```

Use in Products module

```
    constructor(
        @Inject('TestService')
        private readonly TService: TestService,
    ) {}
```

Error:

- If TestService is a provider, is it part of the current ProductsModule?
- If TestService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ProductsModule?

```
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing TestService */ ]
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should import the Appmodule to use serviceTest:

```
    @Module({
  imports: [AppModule],
  controllers: [ProductsController],
  providers: [ProductsService]
})
```

but that not gonna works for Circular dependency problems for more info visit : [circular-dependency](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)

**So the solution** is to create a shared module with services you want to share and to use them, you should only import the module not the service, exp:

```
 @Module({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  controllers: [ProductsController],
  providers: [ProductsService]
})
```

More info about shared modules [shared-modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#shared-modules)